# ggplot geom_smooth exclude negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a linear regression with standard error (se) using ggplot2 geom_smooth which excludes negative values. Using scale_y_continuous unfortunately truncates part of the standard error fill. How can I get the se fill area to smoothly end at y=0?

See example (which uses y=10 rather than y=0, but same process):

```
ymax<-max(mtcars$mpg)
myplot<- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +  
geom_smooth(method=lm,   se=TRUE,fill = "#3399FF", colour="#0000FF",size =1)  +
geom_point(shape=20, size=2) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10, ymax)) 
suppressMessages(print(myplot))
```

I wish I could post the graph, but I have just joined stack overflow and don't have enough reputation points to post images. The graph shows the regression line ending at y=10 as expected, however the se fill ends as a vertical edge (not horizontal with the line below which se should be excluded). Thanks, and sorry I can't post the image :)

Comment: Please consider adding some example data so we can run your plotting code and reproduce the issue. Also, be aware that you can calculate your own error intervals (as `ymin` and `ymax` for each data point) and plot them with `geom_ribbon`.

Comment: if you post the image on some other public image-sharing site, a higher-rep user might retrieve it and edit your question

Comment: Thanks everyone. The new sample data (above) should demonstrate my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to load the `scales` package (`library("scales")`) and change your `scale_y_continuous` formulation to

```
 scale_y_continuous(limit=c(10,ymax),oob=squish)
```

Your other choice is

```
 + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10, ymax))
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works so that the resulting graph shows the standard error corrected. However the lm line now is bent at the y=10 line. The lm should not bend, and should simply stop at y=10.

Comment: yeah, that's hard.

Answer (score 5):

With the new version of ggplot we now need:

```
 scale_y_continuous(limit=c(10,NA),oob=squish)
```